# what is meant by "authority" here?

Tags: android, android-intent

When the URI in an intent is compared to a URI specification in a filter, it's compared only to the parts of the URI included in the filter. For example:

If a filter specifies only a scheme, all URIs with that scheme match the filter.
If a filter specifies a scheme and an authority but no path, all URIs with the same scheme and authority pass the filter, regardless of their paths.
If a filter specifies a scheme, an authority, and a path, only URIs with the same scheme, authority, and path pass the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Authority" is used as a term with `Uri` values using the `content` scheme. Other `Uri` uses, such as for the `http` scheme, will call it the "host". It is the first `Uri` segment after the scheme itself.

So, for a `Uri` like:

```
https://commonsware.com/Android
```

the host is `commonsware.com`. For a `Uri` like:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts
```

the authority is `com.android.contacts`.